# Launch openvpn from a sell script

Tags: bash, openvpn

I have subscribed to a VPN service and now I have a few `.ovpn` files, one for each server. What I'd like to do is creating a shell script in which I can select the file to be loaded, and launch that connection. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TITLE="Start a VPN Connection"
FOLDER=$HOME"/ovpn/"
CHOICE=$(zenity --file-selection --title="Select your desired VPN config" --filename="$FOLDER" --file-filter="*.ovpn")
VPNFILE=$(basename "$CHOICE")

clear
sudo openvpn --cd "$FOLDER" --config "'$VPNFILE'" --verb 1 --auth-user-pass "auth.txt" --auth-nocache
```

Now, the problem is that when I launch this script I can select an .ovpn file, but the script crashes because of this error:

`Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: 'Server-1.ovpn'`

If I edit the last line in my script, using echo instead of sudo, I obtain  a connection string. If I copy&paste that line and manually run the generated command, the connections starts and works good.

Is there something wrong in trying to open a openvpn connection from a shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the single quotes from `"'$VPNFILE'"` or they will be taken to be part of the filename of the configuration file.

Comment: Well you were right! They were left from previous try and errors... dropping those quotes solved my problem. Thanks!